# PHPUnit and DBUnit - getting started

Tags: php, phpunit, dbunit

Does anyone have a link to a good, working tutorial or book on how to get started with adding the DBUnit layer to my PHPUNit tests?

I've tried following the code in

```
protected function getDatabaseTester()
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'pass');
    $connection = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection($pdo);
    $tester = new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DefaultTester($connection);
    $tester->setSetUpOperation(PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Factory::CLEAN_INSERT());
    $tester->setTearDownOperation(PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Factory::NONE());
    /*
    * the next line fails with the error

    PHP Fatal error:  __autoload(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_FlatXMLDataSet.php' (include_path= *** 

    */
    $tester->setDataSet(new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_FlatXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../files/xml_database_export.xml'));
    return $tester;
}
```

The XML is created via **mysqldump** command.  I'd happily use CSV, or even an array in memory (whatever works)

Unfortunately I just can't seem to get this system started.

Answer (score 9):

There is a chapter to Database testing in the PHPUnit manual:

- http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html

<strike>And B. Eberlei's Ultimate Guide to DB Testing with PHPUnit</strike>

- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/dbunit.txt (gone)

<strike>There is also a Blogpost by PHPUnit's author Sebastian Bergmann on the topic (2008 though):</strike>

- [Testing PHP/MySQL Applications with PHPUnit/DbUnit](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/773-Testing-PHPMySQL-Applications-with-PHPUnitDbUnit.html) (removed)

Some even older blog posts by Mike Lively, the author the DbUnit extension can be found at

- http://digitalsandwich.com/?s=dbunit

A more recent tutorial (2010) would be in Matthew Turland's Blog:

- [Database Testing with PHPUnit and MySQL](http://matthewturland.com/2010/01/04/database-testing-with-phpunit-and-mysql/)

You can also visit [#phpunit on Freenode IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/) to get official support.

Comment: After a good amount of time learning DbUnit, I wish someone had told me that it basically just `TRUNCATE`s (erases) a table and populates it with custom data you provide from an XML.  Apparently, that's it. No magical persistent connection, no Avatar-like world of growth and dreams and frolicking through temporary datasets. At the end of the day I can pretty much do the same thing with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` which is even better because it maintains relations. So I'd like to say something like 'don't waste your time with this crappy extension' but due to my limited experience, I won't.

Comment: While I'm here I'll report a couple of things that took me a while to figure out: You need to call `parent::setUp()` if you've got a `setUp()` method, otherwise the database won't populate. And in that method, DbUnit will "helpfully" raise your `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to "exception" level when it's `setUp()`, so even if you had `ERRMODE_SILENT` you'll get exceptions where you're not expecting them.  Also, I can't find an API, so you've got to examine the source code, or read the book, which is like documentation, but longer, with important gems hidden in pages of text. /rant

Comment: Sorry to mislead, above I said `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` maintains relations - actually, it won't maintain foreign keys.  Not to worry though, just roll a `CREATE TABLE` variant to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @Steve That sounds kind of dissapointing, I had higher hopes for DBUnit (seemed a great idea). Maybe it's a bad idea for some reason, but it would be 100 times more useful if each such test would execute some queries within a transaction that is rollbacked in the teardown stage.